# remove responsiveness to nav bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I used `<div id="mws-nav-collapse">` for responsiveness; it worked.

Now I don't need responsiveness, so when I delete this div, I didn't view my nav-bar items in mobile view. How do I make my `nav-bar` items visible in the mobile view without using responsiveness.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="mws-navigation">
    <ul id="link">
        <li data-related="c" class="" id="c1"><a href="#c" title=""   data-toggle="tooltip" class="basic"><i class="icon-calendar"></i>AAA</a></li>
        <li data-related="e" class="" id="e1"><a href="#e" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" class="basic"><i class="icon-tag"></i>BBB</a></li>
        <li data-related="f" class="" id="f1"><a href="#f" data-toggle="tooltip" class="basic"><i class="icon-hdd"></i>CCC</a></li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

the div which i removed

```
<div id="mws-nav-collapse">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is available in bootstrap [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive)

**What changes**

Note the lack of the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`, which disables the zooming aspect of sites in mobile devices. In addition, we reset our container's width and are basically good to go.
Regarding navbars

As a heads up, the navbar component is rather tricky here in that the styles for displaying it are rather specific and detailed. Overrides to ensure desktop styles display are not as performant or sleek as one would like. Just be aware there may be potential gotchas as you build on top of this example when using the navbar.
Browsers, scrolling, and fixed elements

Non-responsive layouts highlight a key drawback to fixed elements. Any fixed component, such as a fixed navbar, will not be scrollable when the viewport becomes narrower than the page content. In other words, given the non-responsive container width of 970px and a viewport of 800px, you'll potentially hide 170px of content.

There is no way around this as it's default browser behavior. The only solution is a responsive layout or using a non-fixed element.

**Example code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <title>Non-responsive Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="non-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

  <body>

    <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
          </form>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
    The text
    </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`non-responsive.css`

```
body {
  padding-top: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

body,
.navbar-fixed-top,
.navbar-fixed-bottom {
  min-width: 970px;
}
.lead {
  font-size: 16px;
}
.page-header {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.page-header .lead {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.container {
  width: 970px;
  max-width: none !important;
}

.col-xs-4 {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  background-color: #eee;
  background-color: rgba(86,61,124,.15);
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border: 1px solid rgba(86,61,124,.2);
}

.container .navbar-header,
.container .navbar-collapse {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}
.navbar-header {
  float: left;
}
.navbar-collapse {
  display: block !important;
  height: auto !important;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  overflow: visible !important;
  visibility: visible !important;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  display: none;
}
.navbar-collapse {
  border-top: 0;
}

.navbar-brand {
  margin-left: -15px;
}
.navbar-nav {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}
.navbar-nav > li {
  float: left;
}
.navbar-nav > li > a {
  padding: 15px;
}

.navbar-nav.navbar-right {
  float: right;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  border-width: 0 1px 1px;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);
          box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
  color: #333;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.navbar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus,
.navbar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
.navbar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
.navbar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
  color: #fff !important;
  background-color: #428bca !important;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a,
.navbar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:hover,
.navbar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:focus {
  color: #999 !important;
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

.navbar-form {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow: none;
}

.navbar-form .form-group {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.navbar-form .form-control {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.navbar-form .form-control-static {
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar-form .input-group {
  display: inline-table;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.navbar-form .input-group .input-group-addon,
.navbar-form .input-group .input-group-btn,
.navbar-form .input-group .form-control {
  width: auto;
}

.navbar-form .input-group > .form-control {
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar-form .control-label {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.navbar-form .radio,
.navbar-form .checkbox {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.navbar-form .radio label,
.navbar-form .checkbox label {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.navbar-form .radio input[type="radio"],
.navbar-form .checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.navbar-form .has-feedback .form-control-feedback {
  top: 0;
}
```

You can find this in [examples](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive/)

Comment: Thank u so much @Sujay...I think it will be better for me to use responsive bcoz of the drawbacks in non-responsive... anyway thank u very much for ur guidance :) :)

Comment: if @Sujay answer is what you are looking for then please accept it as answer.